# Get the 403 when using auth token authenticate for the PowerBI REST API

Tags: authentication, oauth, powerbi, powerbi-rest-api

I want to use token authenticate for the Power BI REST APIs. Now I have a service principal, then I using the az command line to login in and generate the token:

```
az login --service-principal -u ${app_id} -p ${password} --tenant ${tenant_id}

$token= az account get-access-token  --query accessToken
```

And it does get the token.

**However**, I could not authenticate my power bi server, I got the error `403 Forbidden`.

The service principal have the correct rights and add to the workspace access.

In order to verify the permission, I use the source code of a tripartite extension powerbi action:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-power-bi-actions

And there is function [Invoke-API](https://github.com/maikvandergaag/msft-extensions/blob/bc9677d282e011a0c893d4f58000315ba9126a9a/azuredevops/powerbiactions-new/powerbiactionsnew/ps_modules/PowerBi/powerbi.psm1#L269):

```
Function Invoke-API {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Url,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Method,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$Body,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string]$ContentType
    )

    $apiHeaders = Get-PowerBIAccessToken

    ...
    }
    return $result
}
```

It is using the `Get-PowerBIAccessToken` to get the token.

So, I using same service principal to connect powerbi service:

```
$powerbiUrl = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg'
$sp_secret_key = $Env:sp_secret_key | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$organizationType = 'Public'
            
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($sp_client_id, $sp_secret_key)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Environment $organizationType -Tenant $sp_tenant_id -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal

Publish-PowerBIFile -WorkspaceName $target_wrokspace_name -FilePattern "$FilePattern" -Create $Create -Overwrite $Overwrite
```

The function `Publish-PowerBIFile` will invoke the `Invoke-API`. Surprisingly, it worked.

This seems to indicate that my Service Principal has sufficient permissions.

But unfortunately, the execution of this function calling **Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount** requires the installation of the **MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt** function module，Our production environment is in a high security environment and does not allow me to install this module. So I **have to generate a token through Service Principal to complete the authentication**.

**So my question is**, how is the way I generate the token using Service Principal different from the token generated by `Get-PowerBIAccessToken`? What should I do to be successful?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**update:**

I grab the token through `F12` and use postman to verify the token obtained by `F12` and the token obtained by `az account get-access-token --query accessToken`, and it is concluded that the token obtained by `F12` is valid. So **how to generate a valid token through sp or does generating a token require additional permission settings**?

Comment: You can check the source [GetPowerBIAccessToken.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/src/Modules/Profile/Commands.Profile/GetPowerBIAccessToken.cs) and [ServicePrincipalAuthenticationFactory.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/src/Common/Common.Authentication/ServicePrincipalAuthenticationFactory.cs) to see how it works under the hood (and eventually try to use [ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplicationbuilder.build?view=azure-dotnet) directly)

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, Thanks for you suggestion, I have checked that, but I could not to use C# to authenticate, because our project limited to use powershell, and the token is generated by jenkins through pre-step using sp. I can only get it with az account get-access-token --query accessToken. (It seems to be confidential, our operation and maintenance personnel cannot directly contact the sp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `--resource https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api` to your `az account get-access-token` command to retrieve the access token for Power BI Rest APIs.